# How can i convert Framework to Swift Package?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift-package-manager

I have a classic **SMS** Xcode Framework as below, i am using it in some other project.

[image: My Xcode Project]

I like to upgrade my **Framework** to **Swift Package** without changing its existing repo, because i don't want to loose my git traces.

As long as i searched i am getting only information about creating a fresh package from *Xcode->New->Package*, but that is not useful for me in anyway.

If anyone recently did an upgrade like this please let me know.

Thank you in Advance

Comment: You just need to move the files into the correct folder structure and create a Package.swift. For an example of a commit that does this to an existing package, see https://github.com/RNCryptor/RNCryptor/commit/a5102d77c9532c4202b61e2ea3e1d9aace2e12ee  The main thing is moving the files into the correct directories.